# SQL select from 2 tables with restrictions

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

Basically, I have a two tables: management and pictures. 
I need a list with all properties from the management table.  If pictures exist, the list only has to show the first picture (seq=1).

My problem: the list doesn't show the properties without pictures. How do I solve this?

I have the following tables:

tblMan

```
propid | city | lang | ...   
  1      Mol     NL        
  2      Olen    NL        
  3      Geel    NL       
  4      Ham     FR
```

tblPic

```
propid | lang | seq |  filename  
   1      NL     1      file11
   1      FR     1      file12
   1      NL     2      file13
   1      FR     2      file14
   1      NL     3      file15
   1      FR     3      file16
   3      NL     22     file17
   3      FR     22     file18
   3      NL     23     file19
   3      FR     23     file20
   3      NL     24     file21
   3      FR     24     file22

SELECT m.propid, m.city, p.filename
FROM  tblMan as m  
INNER JOIN tblProp as p ON m.propid = p.propid   
WHERE m.lang = 'NL' AND p.lang = 'NL' AND p.picture_index = '1'
```

The result is:

```
propid | city | filename   
  1      Mol     file11
  3      Geel    file17
```

He doesn't get the propid 2 (Olen) because there is no image!

I want the result:

```
propid | city | filename   
  1      Mol     file11
  2      Olen    (Null or 0 or...) 
  3      Geel    file17
```

I tried subquery, union, concat... (@_@) with no result.

Does anybody has an idee what kind of SQL statement I should use?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

use `LEFT JOIN` since you want to display any records on table `tblMan` that matches your condition on the `WHERE` clause and move some filtering condition for table `tblProp` on the `ON` clause

```
SELECT  m.propid, 
        m.city,  
        p.filename
FROM    tblMan as m  
        LEFT JOIN tblProp as p 
           ON m.propid = p.propid 
              AND p.lang = 'NL' 
              AND p.picture_index = '1'   
WHERE   m.lang = 'NL'
```

Comment: This works great. My next problem is: there are pictures where the sequence (picture_index) is starting from 22 or 32 ... instead of 1. When I use min() I get "Invalid use of group function". Thanks!

Comment: can you update this demo with the picture index so I can update the answer? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00c82/2

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.propid, 
       m.city, 
       p.filename 
FROM   tblman AS m 
       LEFT JOIN tblprop AS p 
              ON m.propid = p.propid 
                 AND p.lang = 'NL' 
                 AND p.picture_index = '1' 
WHERE  m.lang = 'NL'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in place of `INNER JOIN`.